# Declare s-expressions types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, s-expression

TypeScript client communicates with server using s-expressions, encoded as JSON. For simplicity let's assume that expression alphabet consist of one terminator function 'rx' which accepts string as parameter and functions 'and', 'or' which accept another expressions as parameters. For example:

```
const msg: Expr = ['and', ['rx', 'a'],
                          ['or', ['rx', 'b'],
                                 ['rx', 'c']]];
```

Straightforward approach to Expr type definition does not work because of illegal recursion:

```
type ExprRx = ['rx', string];
type ExprAnd = ['and', ...Expr[]];
type ExprOr = ['or', ...Expr[]];

type Expr = ExprRx | ExprAnd | ExprOr;
```

How might such type look like? Is it even possible to declare it in modern typescript?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with your samples. I think your code samples should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limitation to the recursive-ness of type aliases, they can't (except under very limited circumstances be recursive). Fortunately interfaces can be recursive. An interface implementation could look something like this:

```
interface ExprRx { op: 'rx', value: string };
interface ExprAnd { op: 'and', operands: Expr[] };
interface ExprOr { op: 'or', operands: Expr[] };

type Expr = ExprAnd | ExprOr | ExprRx;


const msg: Expr = {
    op: 'and',
    operands: [{
        op: 'rx',
        value: 'a'
    }, {
        op: 'or',
        operands: [
            { op: 'rx', value: 'b' },
            { op: 'rx', value: 'c' }
        ]
    }]
};

function evaluate(msg: Expr, map: { [n: string]: boolean}) : boolean {
    // type guards 
    switch (msg.op) {
        case 'rx': return map[msg.value];
        case 'and' : return msg.operands.every(m => evaluate(m, map))
        case 'or' : return msg.operands.some(m => evaluate(m, map))
        default : throw "error";
    }
}
evaluate(msg, {
    'a' : true,
    'b': false,
    'c': false
});
```

Now this version is a bit more verbose then your tuple version. Could we do the same with just tuples ? Well it's a bit more complicated. We can have an interface extend a tuple type and use that but this has several problems. Firstly we can't extend a tuple type directly we will need an extra type alias. Secondly we can't use rest in tuples (not sure why just a complier limitation, I get an error that I incorrectly extend a tuple containing a rest expression). Thirdly, type guards will not work with tuple types such as in the `evaluate` function I wrote above:

```
type Tuple<T0, T1> = [T0, T1]
type TupleRepeat<T0, T1> = [T0, T1, T1]
interface ExprRx extends  Tuple<'rx', string> {};
interface ExprAnd extends TupleRepeat< 'and', Expr> {};
interface ExprOr extends TupleRepeat <'or', Expr> {};

type Expr = ExprRx | ExprAnd | ExprOr

const msg: Expr = ['and', ['rx', 'a'],
                        ['or', ['rx', 'b'],
                                ['rx', 'c']]];


function evaluate(msg: Expr, map: { [n: string]: boolean}) : boolean {
    // no type guards, we need extra assertions.
    switch (msg[0]) {
        case 'rx': return map[msg[1] as string];
        case 'and' : return (msg.slice(1) as Expr[]).every(m => evaluate(m, map))
        case 'or' : return (msg.slice(1) as Expr[]).some(m => evaluate(m, map))
        default : throw "error";
    }
}
evaluate(msg, {
    'a' : true,
    'b': false,
    'c': false
});
```